# WiX bootstrapper that only shows the package Dialogs or atleast one that doesn't require the license approval

Tags: wix

I have a project that I am creating an installer for.  I have the msi created that will do the install but I also need to install some pre-reqs (.NET 4.0 and VSTO client tools or whatever they are called)

From what I can tell I need to use a bootstrapper and while it seems to work I really don't want the default dialogs that make me approve the license.  I would like to skip that completely.  (If I could hide the bootstrapper that would be fine but just having an "Install" button without the EULA would be ok).

Here is the xml I am currently using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLogo" Value="logo.png" />
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>


    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web"/>
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="TestRibbonLocationInstaller.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes"  /> 
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

So from what I can tell I need to basically create a custom bootstrap application for this that I then reference as the bootstrapperapplication.  By doing this I will be able to better control the UI (Basically hide it).

Is this thought process correct?

Comment: Alternative you could use Burn to create a Bundle: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm

Comment: I thought I was using Burn to create the bundle.  Not sure the difference at this point.

Comment: did you see this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991789/how-to-install-net-framework-4-0-as-part-of-installation

Comment: @Josh - with the modified question I can see that you are using Burn. I thought that you where using the VS bootstrapper feature.

Comment: @Josh, did you ever get this implemented?