# Minor problems in deploying Winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a C# Winforms applications. I have some minor issues about it. I am using VS 13 Ultimate.

1) I need to create a Setup file for a **.exe** file.

2) I need to embed my resources in that .exe file.

3) Also, the application says that the database is locked when I open the deployed application.

And, is there any way to install .NET Framework 4.5 automatically which is present in the directory when the target computer does not have the required framework.

Comment: Did you even try to find the answers on your own?

Comment: An issue is when you have something that doesn't do what you want. You're just asking for an explanation, which you should be able to find on the web. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Sandesh that edit didn't improve formatting. Please don't randomly make words bold or hyphenated, that doesn't improve readability at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Wix installer with all appropriate requirements.

1. Quick Wix intro http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with
2. [How to install .NET framework 4.0 as part of installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991789/how-to-install-net-framework-4-0-as-part-of-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new install project to your solution.

Add targets from all projects you want to be installed.

Configure pre-requirements and choose "Check for .NET 4.5 and SQL Express" option.

Choose the location from where missing components must be installed.

Configure your installer settings - company name, version, copyright, etc.

Build and go!